# Excel BeforeDoubleClick Delete Multiple Cells in a Given Row

Tags: vba, excel

This seems so simple, but I'm having a heckava time finding an answer. I'd appreciate any help.

On a Worksheet I have five columns of data, in three groupings:

A1 B1 C1 **D1** E1 ---- J1 K1 L1 **M1** N1 ---- O1 P1 Q1 **R1** S1

A2 B2 C2 **D2** E2 ---- J2 K2 L2 **M2** N2 ---- O2 P2 Q2 **R2** S2

A3 B3 C3 **D3** E3 ---- J3 K3 L3 **M3** N3 ---- O3 P3 Q3 **R3** S3

And so on for 200 rows.

What I want to be able to do in Excel is doubleclick on a cell in the D, M or R column and delete the respective grouping and have that section of the row shift up. For example, I doubleclick on **D2** and A2, B2, C2, D2 and E2 are deleted, shifting up A3, B3, C3, D3 and E3. All other cells remain the same.

In advance, thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.  Please [edit] your post to include the code you have tried and explain where it is failing.  As is this is too broad and will likely receive down votes and closure.

Comment: Scott -- Thanks for the advice. -G

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your worksheet's code module

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Select Case Target.Column
      Case Columns("D").Column, Columns("M").Column, Columns("R").Column
        Target.Offset(, -3).Resize(, 5).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Cancel = True
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: come look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44787615/dictionary-doesnt-display-items-for-certain-key-numeric-value

Answer (score 0):

If the column in always the 3rd column. In VBA paste this code in your sheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If (Target.Column = 4 Or Target.Column = 13 Or Target.Column = 18) Then
        Range(Selection.Offset(0, -2), Selection.Offset(0, 1)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You will want to use Target instead of Selection and you will also want to test to make sure the double click in the desired columns before doing the action.

Comment: Thanks. I was unable to figure out target though. Btw what is the advantage of using target?

Comment: `Target` is what gets returned to the function, Selection could fail as this can change while the code is running.  Just replace all the `selection` with `Target`

Comment: It doesn't work when I try to change the other selection to target. I'll read up a bit more about this and then edit my answer when I understand